# extending structs with (relatively) unknown/arbitrary methods, go reflection(or avoiding reflection)

Tags: reflection, struct, go

The below does not work obviously:

```
Arbitrary := struct {
    field1 string
    field2 string
}{"a", "b"}

fmap := make(map[string]func(string) string)
fmap["fone"] = func(s string) string { fmt.Printf("function fone: %s", s) }
fmap["ftwo"] = func(s string) string { fmt.Printf("function ftwo: %s", s) }

// probably ok, as simple examples go, to this point where reflection needs to be used
// the below does not work 
Arbitrary.fone = fmap["fone"]

Arbitrary.fone("hello")
```

The above is the core of what I'm trying to do: create a struct with values, and then create methods on the struct from a map of functions, or functions passed in. Basically I have a structure with data & ambiguous behavior that needs to be extended with methods unknown until creating the type.

I'm looking for the obvious & inevitable:

1. How to do this in Go
2. Why this shouldn't be done, or can't be done in Go (its possible with the reflect package, I just haven't found examples or reasoned thorough it yet)
3. How this should be done in Go (some sort of interface construct I've not figured out wholly. I've tried an interface which can handle the behavior; but it doesn't account for *other* behaviors that might be added, at the least I haven't figured out interface usage fully yet which is part of the issue)

If you're a person needing complexity [here is the start of the actual task I'm trying to accomplish](https://github.com/thrisp/flotilla/blob/develop/context.go#L19), making that structs behavior extendable.

Comment: Your example doesn't work because it's expecting `func(string) string` and you're using `func(string)`. that being said look at how martini does it.

Comment: I already have spent time looking over Martini, and the framework I'm working with is derived from this down the line. I'm trying to avoid magic and unidiomatic go while still trying to reason through something a still a bit vague in ultimate outcome

Comment: @blueblank you're contradicting yourself, martini is a lot of magic, and a lot of unidiomatic Go. The question you're asking here is also very much related to magic and unidiomatic Go. You're digging a hole here, which you don't need. Use Go to solve your problems, don't use Go to create a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Wessie, I do not see this as digging a hole, I'm asking several things, one of which is accomplishing an objective in the situation in idiomatic Go, without resorting to a frame of multiple reflection.

Answer (score 1):

I completely misunderstood the question.

NO, you can't create a new struct out of thin air and assign fields to it, also even if you could, for the love of everything that's holy, don't do that.

You can use multiple interfaces for example:

```
type Base interface {
    Id() int //all structs must implement this
}
type Foo interface {
    Base
    Foo()
}
type Bar interface {
    Base
    Bar()
}
```

then make a `map[string]Base`, and you can assert the value later.

//leaving the original answer as a different approach to the problem.

<strike>While usually that kind of stuff is done using reflection, if you have a limited number of accepted "callbacks" you can use type assertion and an `interface{}` map, dropping the need for reflection.</strike>

```
var ctx = &Ctx{"Hello"}
var funcs = map[string]interface{}{
    "m3": ctx.Do,
    "m4": func(c *Ctx) { fmt.Println("ctx:", c) },
}

type Ctx struct {
    Name string
}

func (c *Ctx) Do() {
    fmt.Printf("Do: %+v\n", c)
}

func call(m string) {
    if f, ok := funcs[m]; ok {
        switch fn := f.(type) {
        case func():
            fn()
        case func(*Ctx):
            fn(&Ctx{"Hello world"})
        default:
            panic(fn)
        }
    }
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/13jCHzpBic)